# Error in firebase.init: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FIROptions

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript

I added "nativescript-plugin-firebase": plugin. I getting error running on ios simulator, but works fine in Android

```
firebase.init({}).then(() => {console.log("firebase.init done");
},
error => {
  console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
},
)
```

Comment: Try a clean build.

Comment: yes I do that but it's not worked

Answer (score 0):

To solve that, edit firebase.nativescript.json :

> ```
> {
>     "external_push_client_only": false,
>     "using_ios": true,
>     "using_android": true,
>     "messaging": true,
>     "crashlytics": true
> }
> ```

Comment: I edit firebase.nativescript.json but I still get the same erreur

Comment: delete platform folder and re run